# problem with getting image string in json swift 5

Tags: swift

I want to download image and when I run app my app crashed because the image string of json file is like this :

```
images/product/2021-05-02T09-47-17.699Z-download (2).jpg
```

there is a distance between download and (2) in my json file and its the problem that make an app crash , in browser its worked but in Xcode not , what's your idea to solve it?

and here is a part of my code when I want to download image :

```
let imageUrl = URL(string: "http://5.63.13.16:8080/\(item.image.first!)")!
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl) {
        cellol.offerImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
```

Comment: Use URLSession when downloading files and not Data(contentsOf:) so you get asynchronous download.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you very much I use this solution that you mention and I done and its worked thank you brother

Answer (score -2):

you can just use it

```
    func stringCorrection( _ text:String) -> String{
        return text.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
    }
```

use: -

```
let imageUrl = URL(string: "http://5.63.13.16:8080/\(stringCorrection(item.image.first!))")!
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl) {
        cellol.offerImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
```

Comment: The crash will not happening with this answer but the image will not show on the imageView.

Comment: yeah thank you so much brother its working now and imageView is showing the image no problem, really useful answer but you need to add "%20" instead of "" in stringCorrection function and its worked, again thanks brother

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes I agree with you , it is the way that we should learn every thing, but for now I should harry up to solve the project problems, so do you an answer?

Comment: @Alikazemi yes it is in the link I posted to your question above.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ok I check out, thanks

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I angry that its not much batter option for learning purpose but its the quick solution.